# How to retireve the co-ordinates using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

My requirement is to retrieve all the contours and its co-ordinates from an image.
Currently I'm using cvFindContours to find all the contours and then iterating through each using "CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM"/"cvGetSeqElem" to retrieve all the co-ordinates.

Now a new requirement has a come up where by the size of the contours needs to be x pixels less than the actual.

E.g. 
If a circle is found having radius of 100 pixels, then the coordinates returned should be 97 (3 pixels less) pixels. In short any contours (any shape) that will be returned will have x pixels less that the actual.

Is there any API to do so. Like findContours with 3 pixels inner than the actual point.

[image]

The first image is the source and the second image with yellow part should be returned as co-ordinates.

Thanks,
Unni

Comment: I think you shall add a function that will resize the found contour with x/contour_length, or some other ratio...

Comment: Still no idea how to do it. Any other pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As no other suggestions were given, the following method solved my problem:

1. Iterate through each Contours
2. Draw each of the contours in a new blank (clone of the same image), with more thicker line.
3. Found inner contour of the thick line

findcontour
foreach contour in contours
clone image
set 0 in image
drawcontours with contour having pixel width n
findcontour
take inner contour and store for later use
next contour

clone image
set 0 in image
drawcontours with the stored contours
end